# rmagick 2.13.1 - not compatible with imagemagick 6.8.1-9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, rmagick

I am using rails 3.2.9
I have now installed ImageMagick 6.8.1-9 and rmagick 2.13.1 gem.

Once I start the server it returns this error:

```
D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick.rb:11:in `require': This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.5.6 but ImageMagick 6.8.1-9 is in use. (RuntimeError).
```

Is it really because of newer version than rmagick expects?
Any chance to download required ImageMagick version?

thank you.
Petr

Comment: I had to install older version of ImageMagick DLL files and it works now.